# How testing a Map in unit test

Tags: trigger, unit-test, map

I have a trigger which contain a Map and I'd like to test it :

```
trigger AfterLeadUpdate on Lead (after update) {

Map<Id, Lead> leadMap = new Map<Id,Lead>();
Lead parent;

  for (Integer i = 0; i < Trigger.new.size(); i++){
    if (Trigger.new[i].IsConverted == true && Trigger.old[i].isConverted == false) {
      leadMap.put( Trigger.new[i].Id, Trigger.new[i]);
    }
  }

  if( leadMap.size() > 0 ) {
      Set<Id> leadIds = leadMap.keySet();
      List<Ev_nement__c> allChildren = 
        [select Id, Candidat__c, Prospect__c from Ev_nement__c where Prospect__c in :leadIds];       

 System.debug(allChildren);

      for ( Ev_nement__c child : allChildren ) {
        if ( leadMap.containsKey( child.Prospect__c ) ) {
           // lookup the parent lead
           parent = leadMap.get( child.Prospect__c );
           // update the fields on the child object
           child.Candidat__c = parent.ConvertedAccountId;
        }
      }

      update allChildren;
```

So at the line :`if( leadMap.size() > 0 )` I don't know how to make the test.

Now my test class is like that :

```
    @isTest
private class AfterLeadUpdate_TEST {
    @isTest static void AfterLeadUpdate_TEST_OK(){
        Lead prospect = new Lead(LastName = 'test');
        insert prospect;

        Lead pro = [SELECT Id, LastName FROM Lead];

        Map<Id, Lead> leadMap = new Map<Id,Lead>();
        leadMap.put(prospect.Id, prospect);
        leadMap.put(pro.Id, pro);

        Ev_nement__c ev = new Ev_nement__c();
        insert ev;

        List<Ev_nement__c> listEv = new List<Ev_nement__c>();
        listEv.add(ev);
    }
}
```

I try to create the map but it is not working... How can I test that line ?

Thank you :)

Comment: I dont see where you are trying to update the lead in the test method.

Comment: @AslamK I think I forgot to do so, how should I do  that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through your code, you need to convert a lead in order to populate that map.

So the below test should help you do that. May have typo, so you may have to do some debugging.

```
@isTest
private class AfterLeadUpdate_TEST {
    private static void AfterLeadUpdate_TEST_OK(){
        Lead prospect = new Lead(LastName = 'test');
        insert prospect;        

        Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
        lc.setLeadId(prospect.id);

        LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
        lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);

        Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @AslamK it work for my piece of code :) Id didn't know the database  object....